# Get location address in android phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, location

I am making an android application find out your current location, I am not using any map services,

I just want to track the address of application user and display that, I have successfully got the lat long of the location,

How can we get address, city name, street name etc, from the lat long of any location in javascript or AngularJS for an android application

Comment: Refer http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android has a build in [Geocoder API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html), but I'm not sure how that would work with phonegap.  You could also try the [web Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/), which can be used from native Android apps, and which will work with Javascript.